# k&r exercise 1.8 structure members

Tags: c

so I am just going through the basic exercises of the k&r.
The exercise is:
Exercise 1-8. Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines.

I tried to create a structure with the members *blanks,tabs* and *newlines*.
I also coded an init function to set these members to 0.

I will now show you the source code and the output.

```
/*
Exercise 1-8. Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines.
*/

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Counter Counter;

struct Counter
{
    int blanks;
    int tabs;
    int newlines;
};

void initCounter(Counter arg)
{
    arg.blanks = 0;
    arg.tabs = 0;
    arg.newlines = 0;   
};

int main()
{
    int c;
    Counter cnt;
    initCounter(cnt);

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
            if(c == ' ')
            {
                ++cnt.blanks;
            }
            if(c == '\t')
            {
                ++cnt.tabs;
            }
            if(c == '\n')
            {
                ++cnt.newlines;
            }
    }

    printf("\nBlanks: %d", cnt.blanks);
    printf("\nTabs: %d", cnt.tabs);
    printf("\nNewlines: %d\n", cnt.newlines);

return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
give it another try boom

Blanks: -416565517
Tabs: 32768
Newlines: 1
```

Any advice what's going wrong?
Thanks and best regards.

Comment: In chapter 1 you're not supposed to know about structs yet.

Answer (score 5):

```
void initCounter(Counter arg)
{
    arg.blanks = 0;
    arg.tabs = 0;
    arg.newlines = 0;   
};
```

You need to pass a pointer to `arg`. You are initializing a copy of the structure object you pass to `initCounter`. In C function arguments are passed by value.

Your function prototype should be:

```
void initCounter(Counter *arg)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

I let you make the appropriate changes to `initCounter` body and `initCounter` function call.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `initCounter` function:

```
void initCounter(Counter* arg)
{
    arg->blanks = 0;
    arg->tabs = 0;
    arg->newlines = 0;   
}
```

And change the way you are calling it:

```
initCounter(&cnt);
```

As an alternative, you can remove this function altogether, and initialize `cnt` upon declaration:

```
Counter cnt = {0,0,0};
```